# Replace a filename in a JSON document by the contents of that file

Tags: text-processing, json

**My aim:** replace filenames by their contents in a JSON file with a command `sed` or `awk` or other...

**An example:**

- JSON file to modify (`file.json`)

  ```
  ...
        "value": "{{<test/myData.txt>}}"
  ...
  ```

  where the `value` key is located at `.tests[].commands[].value` in the document structure.
- Source file for data (`test/myData.txt`)

  ```
  blabla
  blabla
  ```
- Desired result (`result.json`)

  ```
  ...
        "value": "blabla\nblabla"
  ...
  ```

**My problem:**
I tried with `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/\{\{<([^>]+)>\}\}/{r \1}/" file.json > result.json
```

but the file is not read, I have this result:

```
...
  "value": "{r test/myData.txt}"
...
```

An idea to resolve my problem with `sed` (or a better idea)?

---

**SOLUTION:**

Thank you so much ! All the answers were helpful but I wanted to use a command without installing any new tools in the default environment of GitHub actions.
So I chose between sed and jq because they installed by default.
Sed does not cover automatically conversion of raw strings in a json document, so logically I preferred to use jq.

I use [jq play](https://jqplay.org/) to debug the jq script.

Here the final script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "Utilization:\n"
    printf "$0 <FILE_INPUT> [[--output|-o] <FILE_OUTPUT>]\n"
    printf "example : ./importFile.sh test/testImportFile.side -o aeff.side"
    exit 1
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case $1 in
     --output|-o)
       output="${2}"
       shift
       ;;
    *)
       input="${1}"
  esac
    shift
done

cp -p $input $output

 while : ; do
    cp -p $output "$output.tmp"
    datafile=$(jq -r 'first(.tests[].commands[].value | select(startswith("{{<"))| select(endswith(">}}"))  | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}"))' "$output.tmp")
    #echo "datafile $datafile"
    if [ -z "$datafile" ]; then
        # echo NOT FOUND
        break
    elif [ -f "$datafile" ]; then
       # echo FOUND
       jq --arg data "$(cat "$datafile")" '(first(.tests[].commands[].value | select(startswith("{{<"))| select(endswith(">}}")))) |= $data' "$output.tmp" > $output
    else
        printf 'Could not find "%s" referenced by "%s"\n' "$datafile" $input >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done
rm "$output.tmp"
echo DONE
```

[You can find the project with this script on github.](https://github.com/BorderCloud/selenium-ide-tool-importFile/blob/main/importFile.sh)

Comment: Waou, 2 answers and there are a lot of comments.
@Kusalananda
The context : the feature readFile doesn't exist in Selenium IDE. See issue : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/854
In the meantime, I will make a small script to import the data directly into the JSON :
https://github.com/BorderCloud/selenium-ide-tool-importFile

Comment: I was mostly wondering about the context of the `value` key in the document. Where does it occur in relation to the top-level of the document, for example? The comments to my answer is just me and @cas exchanging personal views about stuff. I was kinda hoping he would weigh in with a solution, but he may be busy with other things.

Comment: @Kusalananda Here is an example of a JSON file: https://github.com/BorderCloud/selenium-ide-tool-importFile/blob/main/test/testImportFile.side

Comment: I see an array called `tests` that has `value` keys. Do you want to process all of these that have values like `{{<something>}}`?

Comment: @Kusalananda The form {{<file name>}} is arbitrary and all repetitions of this pattern must be handled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have issues doing this with `sed` since you will need to both parse the document, decode the pathname stored in the JSON file (it may have certain characters JSON-encoded), and encode the contents of the file for inclusion into the JSON document.  This is certainly *doable* with `sed`, it just means that you have to implement a JSON parser in `sed`.

Let's use an already existing JSON-aware tool, [such as `jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Since we don't see much of the file in the question, I will assume that the file looks something like

```json
{
  "description": "hello world example",
  "value": "{{<test/myData.txt>}}"
}
```

or the equivalent

```json
{"description":"hello world example","value":"{{<test/myData.txt>}}"}
```

i.e., that the `value` key is one of the top-level keys in the JSON file.

What we want to do here is to parse out the value from the `value` key that is between `{{<` and `>}}` and to replace the whole value with that of the file corresponding to the pathname that we are left with.

The pathname could be had using `jq` with

```bsh
jq -r '.value | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}")' file.json
```

This removes the flanking `{{<` and `>}}` and returns the decoded string value.

We can put this string into a shell variable like so:

```bsh
datafile=$( jq -r '.value | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}")' file.json )
```

or we may let `jq` create an assignment statement that we evaluate in the shell (this would allow the pathname to end with a newline),

```bsh
eval "$( jq -r '.value | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}") | @sh "datafile=\(.)"' file.json )"
```

The `@sh` operator ensures that the value that we parse from the JSON file is safely quoted for the shell.  With my example JSON document, this would `eval` the string `datafile='test/myData.txt'`.

Then it's just a matter of getting the file's data and updating that key's value in the original file:

```
jq --arg data "$(cat "$datafile")" '.value |= $data' file.json
```

This creates a `jq` variable `$data` that contains the JSON-encoded data of the file. The data is used to update the value of the `value` key.

The result, given my small example file, and your `test/myData.txt` example file:

```json
{
  "description": "hello world example",
  "value": "blabla\nblabla"
}
```

Then redirect to a new filename if you wish to do so.

Summary:

```bsh
datafile=$( jq -r '.value | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}")' file.json )
jq --arg data "$(cat "$datafile")" '.value |= $data' file.json >result.json
```

Add sanity checking and diagnostic messages to taste:

```bsh
datafile=$( jq -r '.value | ltrimstr("{{<") | rtrimstr(">}}")' file.json )

if [ -f "$datafile" ]; then
    jq --arg data "$(cat "$datafile")" '.value |= $data' file.json >result.json
else
    printf 'Could not find "%s" referenced by "%s"\n' "$datafile" file.json >&2
fi
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127538/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-replace-a-filename-in-a-json-document-by-the).

Answer (score 3):

Using  `python` which has a module `json` to handle json data.

```
python3 -c 'import re, sys, json
jfile,outfile = sys.argv[1:]
regex,rs = re.compile(r"^\{\{<.*>\}\}$"),"\n"

with open(jfile) as f:
  d = json.load(f)

for el in d["tests"]:
  for lod in el["commands"]:
    if re.search(regex,lod["value"]):
      txtfile = re.sub(r"^\{\{<|>\}\}$","",lod["value"])
      with open(txtfile) as t:
        contents = "".join(t.readlines()).rstrip(rs)
        break
  else:
    continue
  break

for el in d["tests"]:
  for lod in el["commands"]:
    lod["value"] = contents

with open(outfile,"w") as w:
  json.dump(d,w,indent=2)
' file.json result.json
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very basic example in perl using the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/release/JSON) library module.

The script will recursively iterate through **all** the keys of the json data, replacing any and all keys which match the file inclusion regex (`\{\{<([^>]*)>\}\}/`) and replacing the value for that key with the contents of the file.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use JSON;
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

local $/; # read entire files at once

my $text = <>;  # slurp file.json into $text

my $json = JSON->new->canonical;  # canonical causes the keys to be sorted
my $j = $json->decode($text);
#dd $j;

process_includes($j);
#dd $j;

print $json->pretty->encode($j);


sub process_includes {
  # This subroutine recursively iterates through all the
  # keys, replacing values which match {{<filename>}}
  # with the contents of "filename".

  my $h = shift;   # expects a hashref containing json data

  foreach my $key (keys %$h) {

    if ($h->{$key} =~ m/\{\{<([^>]*)>\}\}/) {
      # we have a match, slurp in the file and apply it.

      my $file = $1;

      # read the file
      open(my $fh,"<",$file) or die "couldn't open '$file': $!\n";
      my $contents = <$fh>;
      close($fh);

      # replace the value with the file contents
      $h->{$key} = $contents;

    } elsif (ref($h->{$key}) eq "HASH") {

      # we have a hashref, so recurse into it.
      process_includes($h->{$key});
    };
  }
}
```

Save it as, e.g., `json-include.pl`, and make executable with `chmod +x json-include.pl`, then run it:

```
$ ./json-include.pl file2.json 
{
   "tests" : {
      "andthis" : {
         "foo" : "blabla\nblabla\n"
      },
      "commands" : {
         "value" : "blabla\nblabla\n"
      },
      "includethis" : "blabla\nblabla\n"
   }
}
```

`file2.json` contains:

```
$ cat file2.json 
{
   "tests" : {
      "commands" : {
         "value" : "{{<test/myData.txt>}}"
      },
      "includethis" : "{{<test/myData.txt>}}",
      "andthis" : {
         "foo" : "{{<test/myData.txt>}}"
      }
   }
}
```

Note: I've used the same filename each time above, but you can use any filenames you like, as long as it exists and contains valid data.  The filename can be an absolute pathname, or relative to the current directory.

---

You can use perl's [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/release/Data-Dump) module to get a nicely formatted dump of `$j` after it has been decoded, which will show you what your json data looks like as a perl object.  This will make it easier to find the keys you want to work with (and is also useful for debugging).  I've left commented-out examples in the code.

For file2.json above, the output **before** processing with `process_includes()` would look like:

```
{
  tests => {
    andthis     => { foo => "{{<test/myData.txt>}}" },
    commands    => { value => "{{<test/myData.txt>}}" },
    includethis => "{{<test/myData.txt>}}",
  },
}
```

BTW, it should be obvious that this isn't all that dis-similar to a json data file - perl Hashes-of-Hashes (HoH, see `man perldsc` and `man perlreftut` for details on perl data structures) are pretty similar to json...or, at least, there's a pretty direct translation between them.

After processing, it would look like:

```
{
  tests => {
    andthis     => { foo => "blabla\nblabla\n" },
    commands    => { value => "blabla\nblabla\n" },
    includethis => "blabla\nblabla\n",
  },
}
```

A real json file will have much more data and be a lot more complicated.

---

BTW, on debian you can install `Data::Dump` and `JSON` with `sudo apt install libjson-perl libdata-dump-perl`.  They should be available as packages for most other distros too.  Otherwise, install with `cpan`.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '/{{/!b;h
s/.*<\|>.*//g
s/.*/cat &/e
s/\n/\\n/g
x;s/{.*//
G;s/\n//
s/$/"/' file.json
```

Comment: would you care to explain how it works ?

Comment: That could break in so many ways based on the input contents. sed is just the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @EdMorton, Agree. Let it be an example of how not to do this